# Uninstall Intel Chipset Software INF Utility?

Tags: uninstall

Have a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM that somehow has installed on it the Intel Chipset Device Software.  The software is triggering an audit on

"Intel Chipset Device Software INF Utility information disclosure vulnerability (INTEL-SA-00306)."

Since it is a VM, installing the latest Intel Chipset Device Software fails with a 0x00004E24 This platform is not supported.  So upgrading isn't an option apparently.

Given this is a VM can it be uninstalled?  If so how best to do so?

And is this statement from Intel correct?

"There is no need to uninstall the Intel® Chipset Software Installation Utility; therefore, there is no uninstall utility included with the software."

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000006081/software/chipset-software.html

Comment: Try the technique in this Lenovo support article to uninstall Chipset. It is the technique I point you to (not Lenovo or vendor specific).  https://support.lenovo.com/tr/en/troubleshoot/lpt000338

Comment: If @John solution doesn't work for you, use the PNPUtil command line utility like this `pnputil /enum-drivers`.  Look for the entries that have oem in the name.. like `Published Name:     oem69.inf` and `Provider Name:      Intel` (or Intel Corporation).  Once you find your `oem69.inf` or whatever, use the command `pnputil /delete-driver oem69.inf /force` to delete the package.  After that,, when you remove the device, it wont auto-reinstall.

Comment: Also, look at `pnputil /?`.  You can possibly find a quicker way looking at the enum options to find what you are looking for.  I usually dump the output from the enum-drivers command to a text file and look through it using a text editor.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thanks.  I did dump the pnputil output.  There were no entries for anything "chipset".  Do you think deleting the dll and files mentioned in the registry path HKLM\SOFTWARE\Intel\Network_Services\Infinst\Uninstall would do the trick?

Comment: No, I personally wouldn't delete the entries by hand.. they will just get reinstalled anyways (since the actual INF file is now in the driver store), look for anything Intel that has an "oemXX.inf" name and remove then also using the pnputil based on your better judgement.  All of the oem stuff is added after the fact and should not break your machine.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thanks. So I went ahead and deleted dll and inf files from the disk where the registry said they were (syswow64 and driverstore).  Also deleted the registry HKLM\SOFTWARE\Intel\Network_Services\Infinst.  Rebooted. Nothing bad appeared in the Windows Event system log.  So that is promising.  I won't be able to validate the Audit until the audit group does their rescan.